# What causes a Crashed dumped error when adding labels to large file?

Tags: qgis, labeling, mmqgis

I created a world grid (rectangles) using mmqgis and joined a CSV file to the attribute table in order to label the grid.

Everything runs fine but when I try to add labels to the grid I get a minidump and QGIS shuts down.  Smaller sample sizes of the same data work fine.

Am I trying to do too much by adding 90,000+ labels?

Comment: What results occur from the minidump, can you post more details to your question?

Comment: I edited it, but it just shuts down.

Comment: Can you provide test data? Otherwise there is not much to go on here ...

Comment: It works with a smaller sample but the full layer crashes qgis.  How do I share the data?